Changing Firebase Rules to be more restrictive
My existing Firebase realtime database currently uses the below rules and it works great for a single user:
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "confirmations": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}

But I would like to add additional users with less access. I tried the below, but the additional users are not able to create new objects in the database.
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null", // All authenticated users can read
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'AdminUID' || (!data.exists() && newData.exists())",
    ".validate": "auth.uid === 'AdminUID' || (!data.exists() && newData.exists())"
  }
}

(I did change AdminUID to the actual UID, but that shouldn't be the only problem anyway with other users not being able to create new, although they are able to read and they aren't able to modify existing)
I'd like the admin to be able to read, modify existing, delete or create new, but other users I'd only like to be able to read and create new proposals and not modify existing or delete. What am I missing here?

Security rules on themselves do nothing. They only become active when you execute code against them. Please edit your question to show the minimal code that doesn't work as you expect it to agianst these rules.

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your Firebase Console.
